# Скачать изображение из диалога вк посредством VkNet

Tags: c#, .net, vknet

Необходимо скачать изображение из диалога вконтакте.
Диалог идет между пользователем и сообществом, мы выступаем сообществом.

Авторизуемся при помощи токена

```
var api = new VkApi();
api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
{
    AccessToken = "мой_токен",

});
```

Получаем неотвеченные диалоги сообщества:

```
var messagesGet = api.Messages.GetDialogs(new MessagesDialogsGetParams
{
    Count = 200,
    Unanswered = true
});
```

Получаем список всех вложений(прикреплённых к сообщениям фото):

```
MessagesGetHistoryAttachmentsParams attachmentsParams = new MessagesGetHistoryAttachmentsParams();
attachmentsParams.MediaType = VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.MediaType.Photo;
foreach (var mes in messagesGet.Messages)
{
    string str;
    attachmentsParams.PeerId = 291249709;
    List<HistoryAttachment>attachments =api.Messages.GetHistoryAttachments(attachmentsParams, out str).ToList();  
    foreach(HistoryAttachment attachment in attachments)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Photo photo = (Photo)attachment.Attachment.Instance;
        MessageBox.Show(photo.BigPhotoSrc.ToString()); //на этой строке получаем ошибку System.NullReferenceException
    }  
}
```

При попытке получить ссылку на изображение для дальнейшей загрузки (`photo.BigPhotoSrc.ToString()`) получаем исключение со следующим текстом:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
>   `VkNet.Model.Attachments.Photo.BigPhotoSrc.get` вернул `null`.

**Через отладчик удалось узнать,что многие поля Photo определены как null,в частности и PhotoSrc,который я запрашиваю**

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дело в том,что некоторые свойства переменной photo не заполняются,в частности PhotoSrc,я хочу узнать,почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с [версии 5.77](https://vk.com/dev/versions) у API изменился вид объекта [photo](https://vk.com/dev/objects/photo), где сервер не отдает такие значения как `photo_***`. Все размеры и адреса  изображений по прежнему можно достать из массива `sizes` из которого мы можем взять нужный нам размер по значению [type](https://vk.com/dev/photo_sizes).

Мы можем сами глянуть то, что отправляет нам сервер, отправив запрос через [dev сайт](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistoryAttachments).
В ответе нам будет примерно такой JSON:

```
{
  "response": {
    "items": [
      {
        "message_id": 1234567,
        "attachment": {
          "type": "photo",
          "photo": {
            "id": 456287182,
            "album_id": 123,
            "owner_id": 123456,
            "user_id": 1234567,
            "sizes": [
              {
                "type": "m",
                "url": "https://sun1-2.us...160/6BPQrmj9Nh4.jpg",
                "width": 130,
                "height": 77
              },
              {
                "type": "o",
                "url": "https://sun1-12.u...165/KiMroLu-9A8.jpg",
                "width": 130,
                "height": 87
              },
              {
                "type": "p",
                "url": "https://sun1-14.u...166/E5bfvlBnLCk.jpg",
                "width": 200,
                "height": 133
              }
            ],
            "text": "",
            "date": 123456789,
            "access_key": "********"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "next_from": "123456/1"
  }
}
```

Как видим, сервер не отдает нам `photo_***`, но `sizes` на месте!

---

Также хочу заметить, что использованный Вами метод [messages.getDialogs](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getDialogs) с [версии 5.80](https://vk.com/dev/versions) объявлен устаревшим! Советую вам перейти на более новый метод [messages.getConversations](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations).